# Tumbler's first TumblerColumn is empty

Tags: qml

I am working on following [QML's Tumbler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-extras-tumbler.html#details):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Item
{
    id: ueDisplayTimeoutSettingsWindow

    width: 640
    height: 480

    RowLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

            spacing: 32

            Tumbler
            {
                id: ueDisplayTimeoutSelector

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop

                antialiasing: true

                TumblerColumn
                {
                    id: ueTumblerDigit100

                    readonly property int ueValue: currentIndex*100

                    width: ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.width/ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.columnCount-12

                    model: 10
                }   // TumblerColumn

                TumblerColumn
                {
                    id: ueTumblerDigit10

                    readonly property int ueValue: currentIndex*10

                    width: ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.width/ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.columnCount-12

                    model: 10
                }   // TumblerColumn

                TumblerColumn
                {
                    id: ueTumblerDigit1

                    readonly property int ueValue: currentIndex

                    width: ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.width/ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.columnCount-12

                    model: 10
                }   // TumblerColumn

                style: TumblerStyle
                {
                    visibleItemCount: 5

                    spacing: 4

                    background: Rectangle
                    {
                        color: "transparent"
                    }   // background

                    frame: Rectangle
                    {
                        color: "transparent"

                        border.color: "steelblue"
                        border.width: 1

                        radius: 8
                    }   // frame

                    columnForeground: Rectangle
                    {
                        border.width: 2
                        border.color: "steelblue"

                        opacity: 0.30

                        radius: 16

                        gradient: Gradient
                        {
                            GradientStop
                            {
                                position: 0.00
                                color: "#191919"
                            }   // GradientStop

                            GradientStop
                            {
                                position: 0.50
                                color: "#2f2f2f"
                            }   // GradientStop
                        }   // gradient
                    }   // columnForeground

                    delegate: Text
                    {
                        text: styleData.value

                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                        opacity: 0.4+Math.max(0,
                                              1-Math.abs(styleData.displacement))*0.6

                        color: "steelblue"

                        font.pixelSize: 48
                    }   // delegate
                }   // style
            }   // Tumbler

            TextField
            {
                id: ueDisplayTimeoutTextField

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: false
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignBottom

                horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

                //inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhPreferNumbers|Qt.ImhDigitsOnly

                readOnly: true

                text: ueTumblerDigit100.ueValue+ueTumblerDigit10.ueValue+ueTumblerDigit1.ueValue+" "+qsTr("s")

                style: TextFieldStyle
                {
                    background: Rectangle
                    {
                        color: "transparent"

                        RowLayout
                        {
                            anchors.fill: parent

                            BorderImage
                            {
                                Layout.fillWidth: false
                                Layout.fillHeight: true
                                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                                source: "qrc:///icons/ueTextLine.png"
                            }   // BorderImage
                        }   // RowLayout
                    }   // background

                    placeholderTextColor: "steelblue"

                    renderType: Text.NativeRendering

                    textColor: "lightsteelblue"

                    //font.pixelSize: 48
                }   // style
            }   // TextField
        }   // ColumnLayout
    }   // RowLayout
}   // Item
```

and here is its result:
[image: Fist Column is empty]
Now, if I *work* with this `Tumbler`, everything is ok, however, **at startup first [QML Tumbler Column](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickEnterpriseControls/qml-qtquick-enterprise-controls-tumblercolumn.html#details)** is empty, the other two are perfect (from the code it can be seen they are **identical**). Why?!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that runs?

Comment: @Mitch the code now works in `Qt Creator's Designer`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the tumbler isn't completely gone. Once you start dragging it down it appears. The problem seems to be in the width statements.

```
  width: ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.width/ueDisplayTimeoutSelector.columnCount-12
```

When you replace the three statements with - lets say 180.

```
   width: 180
```

It works. I have no idea why though. Possibly you need to define the variable before and then fill it because calculating the width statement within leads to trouble...